failed to verify snapshot bank for slot when starting validator on mainnet
I am trying to start a RPC node, but it keeps on crashing with the following panic:
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.653377509Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] Rebuilt bank for slot: 300607256
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663454554Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils] rebuild bank from snapshots took 72.4s
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663492643Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Cleaning... Skipped.
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663498783Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Shrinking... Skipped.
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663503173Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Verifying accounts...
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663852570Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Verifying accounts... In background.
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.663857800Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Verifying bank...
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.664199807Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Initial background accounts hash verification has started
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.666152868Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] skipped rewrite hashes 300607256 0
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.668560656Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] bank frozen: 300607256 hash: G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J accounts_delta: 4Ah6V1EkdKH1AAhe3AwUHf7rHxxPj8xdBAtj1RNJSpAo signature_count: 3075 last_blockhash: Bj3dmniMKq4oqDWrTTLg3FJUZKR5vz8RPADwjnd5PEw5 capitalization: 588077744187801189, stats: BankHashStats { num_updated_accounts: 8269, num_removed_accounts: 103, num_lamports_stored: 8414578401973540, total_data_len: 24673665, num_executable_accounts: 0 }
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.668599155Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300607256, G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J (calculated) != 4N3ofbE9Dz1HQe9vq8dYU2BKexm6xkkAecWgkn1MzPhJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.668605405Z INFO  solana_runtime::bank] Verifying bank... Done.
thread 'main' panicked at /f/repos/solana/runtime/src/snapshot_bank_utils.rs:379:9:
Snapshot bank for slot 300607256 failed to verify
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.668632465Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: verify_snapshot_bank clean_us=5i shrink_us=5i verify_accounts_us=354i verify_bank_us=4741i
stack backtrace:
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.790083782Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active hash=1i
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.790972773Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: accounts_db_active hash_scan=1i
[2024-11-10T17:35:03.010904032Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: net-stats-validator in_datagrams_delta=0i no_ports_delta=0i in_errors_delta=0i out_datagrams_delta=0i rcvbuf_errors_delta=0i sndbuf_errors_delta=0i in_csum_errors_delta=0i ignored_multi_delta=0i in_errors=35617950i rcvbuf_errors=35617944i sndbuf_errors=0i rx_bytes_delta=3353i rx_packets_delta=47i rx_errs_delta=0i rx_drops_delta=0i rx_fifo_delta=0i rx_frame_delta=0i tx_bytes_delta=5478i tx_packets_delta=26i tx_errs_delta=0i tx_drops_delta=0i tx_fifo_delta=0i tx_colls_delta=0i
   0: rust_begin_unwind
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
   2: solana_runtime::snapshot_bank_utils::bank_from_snapshot_archives
   3: solana_ledger::bank_forks_utils::load_bank_forks
   4: solana_core::validator::Validator::new
   5: solana_validator::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
[2024-11-10T17:35:03.659231199Z ERROR solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: panic program="validator" thread="main" one=1i message="panicked at /f/repos/solana/runtime/src/snapshot_bank_utils.rs:379:9:
    Snapshot bank for slot 300607256 failed to verify" location="/f/repos/solana/runtime/src/snapshot_bank_utils.rs:379:9" version="2.0.0 (src:00000000; feat:3257402020, client:SolanaLabs)"
[2024-11-10T17:35:27.329745127Z INFO  solana_validator] solana-validator 2.0.0 (src:00000000; feat:3257402020, client:SolanaLabs)

The systemctl service then restart the validator, but it crashes after 5mns for the same slot or a new one from time to time:
[2024-11-10T14:26:58.445614061Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300582751, FYqxNWzJYnXWBKvoK5B9dvzguDcF1ogkT7qXHaCsVHsG (calculated) != BsT5n6UzEfdcnVSwEuzoBXKCMxhhNk1vWhdv3HtPsaUi (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:31:18.138005163Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300582751, FYqxNWzJYnXWBKvoK5B9dvzguDcF1ogkT7qXHaCsVHsG (calculated) != BsT5n6UzEfdcnVSwEuzoBXKCMxhhNk1vWhdv3HtPsaUi (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:35:39.550621030Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300582751, FYqxNWzJYnXWBKvoK5B9dvzguDcF1ogkT7qXHaCsVHsG (calculated) != BsT5n6UzEfdcnVSwEuzoBXKCMxhhNk1vWhdv3HtPsaUi (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:39:54.814699910Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300582751, FYqxNWzJYnXWBKvoK5B9dvzguDcF1ogkT7qXHaCsVHsG (calculated) != BsT5n6UzEfdcnVSwEuzoBXKCMxhhNk1vWhdv3HtPsaUi (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:47:26.387009061Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300585564, 9qQbBN5uWv6D5kDFcSqZsbzYSq33XnCtoD4SM4s42ECE (calculated) != H9CqpMiQLzfK169EaUrB7MZxTtjVz1XgNxYH9m77LzzJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:51:44.421654377Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300585564, 9qQbBN5uWv6D5kDFcSqZsbzYSq33XnCtoD4SM4s42ECE (calculated) != H9CqpMiQLzfK169EaUrB7MZxTtjVz1XgNxYH9m77LzzJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T14:56:05.160508326Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300585564, 9qQbBN5uWv6D5kDFcSqZsbzYSq33XnCtoD4SM4s42ECE (calculated) != H9CqpMiQLzfK169EaUrB7MZxTtjVz1XgNxYH9m77LzzJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:00:31.783194254Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300585564, 9qQbBN5uWv6D5kDFcSqZsbzYSq33XnCtoD4SM4s42ECE (calculated) != H9CqpMiQLzfK169EaUrB7MZxTtjVz1XgNxYH9m77LzzJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:05:16.422511662Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300588317, FBNNQ7LoAtkuUaCYV8Pf6ybjb7qXKPiEVFRAQkpvutz7 (calculated) != 94YkwTkfTnhDBx6yNTtcYxwGPfn26pSagvY3WNfX7TEX (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:09:37.508813852Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300588317, FBNNQ7LoAtkuUaCYV8Pf6ybjb7qXKPiEVFRAQkpvutz7 (calculated) != 94YkwTkfTnhDBx6yNTtcYxwGPfn26pSagvY3WNfX7TEX (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:13:52.874639980Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300588317, FBNNQ7LoAtkuUaCYV8Pf6ybjb7qXKPiEVFRAQkpvutz7 (calculated) != 94YkwTkfTnhDBx6yNTtcYxwGPfn26pSagvY3WNfX7TEX (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:18:13.495446369Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300588317, FBNNQ7LoAtkuUaCYV8Pf6ybjb7qXKPiEVFRAQkpvutz7 (calculated) != 94YkwTkfTnhDBx6yNTtcYxwGPfn26pSagvY3WNfX7TEX (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:22:47.358612185Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300588317, FBNNQ7LoAtkuUaCYV8Pf6ybjb7qXKPiEVFRAQkpvutz7 (calculated) != 94YkwTkfTnhDBx6yNTtcYxwGPfn26pSagvY3WNfX7TEX (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:27:49.855374428Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:32:13.167521541Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:36:34.781898367Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:41:02.692418413Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:45:27.307466712Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T15:49:52.119217181Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300591149, 6KyN6frEZdECWF9FnvpyTQbghXTFHBs83eEo1VAt1UdS (calculated) != De2M41LA9EgPyP6Wiev16TCRUL8JqVkhFBdByQrmrvRS (expected)
[2024-11-10T16:51:02.998125755Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300602060, HNJa7tUVC6pqbWwbbxUXzqDWvqLxzhpCQ3z2GsYCZUQP (calculated) != 7UcR6E7WXEMAmdWmJeqiL9hPbz6Ac6iZLxgVZyS7BfcC (expected)
[2024-11-10T16:55:38.808447379Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300602060, HNJa7tUVC6pqbWwbbxUXzqDWvqLxzhpCQ3z2GsYCZUQP (calculated) != 7UcR6E7WXEMAmdWmJeqiL9hPbz6Ac6iZLxgVZyS7BfcC (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:00:10.122491928Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300602060, HNJa7tUVC6pqbWwbbxUXzqDWvqLxzhpCQ3z2GsYCZUQP (calculated) != 7UcR6E7WXEMAmdWmJeqiL9hPbz6Ac6iZLxgVZyS7BfcC (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:04:33.542603312Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300602060, HNJa7tUVC6pqbWwbbxUXzqDWvqLxzhpCQ3z2GsYCZUQP (calculated) != 7UcR6E7WXEMAmdWmJeqiL9hPbz6Ac6iZLxgVZyS7BfcC (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:11:13.558409543Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300604694, CHsBTEH2HpwyuqKV1PDsx8w37m4MemwgqFtbk4dMizCB (calculated) != FTWZnu1xBdVM1GKSGepyo2yZ6Rgd4SYFicd7ffSHJBqM (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:15:38.738150313Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300604694, CHsBTEH2HpwyuqKV1PDsx8w37m4MemwgqFtbk4dMizCB (calculated) != FTWZnu1xBdVM1GKSGepyo2yZ6Rgd4SYFicd7ffSHJBqM (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:19:58.939308940Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300604694, CHsBTEH2HpwyuqKV1PDsx8w37m4MemwgqFtbk4dMizCB (calculated) != FTWZnu1xBdVM1GKSGepyo2yZ6Rgd4SYFicd7ffSHJBqM (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:24:27.157754502Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300604694, CHsBTEH2HpwyuqKV1PDsx8w37m4MemwgqFtbk4dMizCB (calculated) != FTWZnu1xBdVM1GKSGepyo2yZ6Rgd4SYFicd7ffSHJBqM (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:30:33.108105425Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300607256, G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J (calculated) != 4N3ofbE9Dz1HQe9vq8dYU2BKexm6xkkAecWgkn1MzPhJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:35:02.668599155Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300607256, G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J (calculated) != 4N3ofbE9Dz1HQe9vq8dYU2BKexm6xkkAecWgkn1MzPhJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:39:25.271811630Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300607256, G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J (calculated) != 4N3ofbE9Dz1HQe9vq8dYU2BKexm6xkkAecWgkn1MzPhJ (expected)
[2024-11-10T17:43:43.082004542Z WARN  solana_runtime::bank] verify failed: slot: 300607256, G1eEsFUp6jq9ZSBFEFm8ZAUvxV1w34qaDmtep28hVs1J (calculated) != 4N3ofbE9Dz1HQe9vq8dYU2BKexm6xkkAecWgkn1MzPhJ (expected)


I tried emptying my ledger and account data but this didn't help.
I built solana from source on current master.
My startup script is:
#!/bin/bash
exec /f/bin/solana-validator \
    --identity /home/sol/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription \
    --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /f/ledger \
    --accounts /f/accounts \
    --log /home/sol/solana-rpc.log \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --private-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --limit-ledger-size

How can I fix this verification issues so that my node can start?
